# Testing my site for accessibility to readers

Tags: web-development, accessibility

What are some quick and easy ways to determine if my web site is healthy or poor when it comes to accessibility to readers and other like devices?

I don't have a reader, but need a way to test so that I can improve the site in this area. Are there any coding strategies or methods for testing this?

Comment: Are you talking about making sure that your content is at an appropriate reading level for your audience, or asking about how to simulate a screen reader that speaks your page for blind users?

Comment: I would be interested in both areas

Comment: You can also remove any CSS, or inline styles. Check out the _real_ flow of the content rather than what has been forced by style controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a free screen reader program for Windows called NVDA. It can be downloaded here: https://www.nvaccess.org/download/

Macs come with a screen reader program called Voiceover, WebAIM has an article on how to use it: http://webaim.org/articles/voiceover/

I found it very enlightening as a sighted person to try navigating some websites via a screen reader. Experiencing the frustration first-hand of dealing with a badly coded website really helped drive home the importance of doing this correctly.

Comment: I especially appreciate the last paragraph. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a site I use for stuff like this sometimes.  It's not aimed at accessibility, per se, but it's a good way to see how your site renders on various platforms.  http://browsershots.org/

If you need further assistance with font-sizing, check this out:

https://medium.com/@madhum86/css-font-sizing-pixels-vs-em-vs-rem-vs-percent-vs-viewport-units-b1485716afe7